# Can I give an alias to an imported library in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, import, alias

I'm having troubles with the following. I have been working for a while with a model called `Location`, but now I found that angular also has such a model so I have the following collision in one component where I need both:

```js
import { Location } from 'src/app/core/models/location.model';
import { Location }  from '@angular/common';
```

Is there any workaround for this such as giving an alias to the library?

Current issue:

> Duplicate identifier 'Location'.ts(2300)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can alias imports using the `as` keyword to avoid name collisions.

```js
import { Location as LocationModel } from 'src/app/core/models/location.model';
import { Location }  from '@angular/common';
```