# Can I extend a service and override its name declaration?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to extend the CDK Overlay service.

I created my custom MyOverlayService like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyOverlayService extends Overlay { ... }
```

and in my app.module.ts provides I added this:

```
{
  provide: Overlay,
  useClass: MyOverlayService
}
```

It works correctly. Now, what I would like to do is to override completely the Overlay service with my custom one, so whenever I inject Overlay in a component, I'm injecting my custom service. So basically something like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Overlay extends Overlay { ... }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How should typescript know which `Overlay` you mean? You cannot choose the same name for two different classes in the same file. Also you cannot hide a class from a package.

Comment: why is overwriting the provider isn't enough for you?

Comment: Because MyOverlayService and Overlay are different instances.
So if someone creates an overlay using Overlay, but then I need some method from MyOverlayService, they will not be available since they are 2 different services.
I would like to prevent someone from using the native Overlay service completely, so they would always use MyOverlayService.

Comment: It might be possible to limit TypeScript imports with third party tools, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52579681/5470544 Also it's possible to alias an import, so you can name your own service `Overlay`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66837054/5470544

Comment: I don't think that would work. I won't to prevent the usage of the original Overlay service in the whole application, and just use the extended one.
Is there a way to prohibit the usate of the parent service?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is this:

```
providers: [
  MyOverlayService,
  { provide: Overlay, useExisting: MyOverlayService},
]
```

in this way if you inject either `Overlay` or `MyOverlayService`, your instance will be provided. Thus your old code that used `Overlay` would work. In case some piece of code would require new functionality that only exists in `MyOverlayService`, it can `inject(MyOverlayService)` without any issues.

Comment: I tried doing that, but if someone injects Overlay instead of MyOverlayService, it won't have access to MyOverlayService new methods.
What do you mean by "inject(MyOverlayService)"? Where would you do that?

Comment: look. you are providing shared functionality. if user(who is using your functionality) is happy with the old interface, then they would just inject `Overlay`. if you override parent methods in `MyOverlayService`, they will be called, even if user injects just `Overlay`. If user wants to use new methods, then they just change `Overlay` to `MyOverlayService`. And everything remains the same because of polymorphism rules. Just the new methods would be also accessible